# Azure DevOps go the next stage after canceling the previous

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

how can I in azure devops using Pre-deployment approvals, after clicking cancel go to the next stage?

I thought  use gate and resy api, I don’t know.

Comment: In which scenario, would you want to go to the next stage even when cancelling the previous one? Unless, you want to deploy on both stages independent of each other

Comment: @RJain let's say in one stage the web app slots are turn on,  after find erroe  on a  stage QA, I click cancel and the process has stopped, but in the next stage I have step for the slots turn off, but it doesn’t reach this stage, and I’d like that would operation or stage for stop slots dor web app is worked anyway

Comment: well from process wise, I would still not create a separate stage for clean up, instead I would create these tasks within the release pipeline and then run them always even before the previous steps fail. But, I am still not sure how you can verify the error on QA during deployment. Are you using a Manual intervention task?

Comment: @RJain , yes I use Pre-deployment approvals

Comment: I thought write an azure function to poll stage and then add it to gates

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to continue the stage after clicking cancel.Because a stage will not be triggered at all if the pre-deployment condition is rejected.

So, just as R Jain suggested in the comments, if the clean up task is necessary regardless of the success of the previous task, then it is a good choice to add it in previous task. This is logically reasonable.

Though, you can add a separated stage to perform the clean task which does not need pre-deployment condition.

[image]

Comment: I thought write an azure function to poll stage and then add it to gates

Answer (score 0):

If the trigger for your next stage selection is **After stage**, then canceling the previous stage will not trigger the next stage. The trigger for the next stage is based on the successful deployment of the previous stage.

From your words "after find erroe on a stage QA, I click cancel " ,we can know that you should manually intervene in the deployment. Then you can choose **After release** trigger for the next stage.So even if the QA stage is canceled, you can go to the next stage.
[image]

Comment: I thought write an azure function to poll stage and then add it to gates

Comment: If you have any progress, thank you for sharing it.